# why is this c program giving runtime error

Tags: c

my program is to take input of integers and  add sum of odd negative numbers to even positive numbers but i am getting runtime error,can anyone find mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
 {

int i,j,m,n,a[m],w;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   int s=0,d=0;
        scanf("%d",&m);
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[j]);  
            if((a[j]<0)&&(a[j]%2!=0))
             s=s+a[j];
        else if((a[j]>0)&&(a[j]%2==0))
        d=d+a[j];
        }
        printf("%d",s+d);
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int i,j,m,n,a[m],w;`. Did you _actually_ do that?

Comment: At least try to use meaningful variable names.
It will make things much easier for you later on.

Answer (score 6):

in your code

```
a[m]
```

is erroneous. value of `m` is used as uninitialized.

To solve your issue, you can use dynamic memory allocation for a variable `int * a` based on the user input of `m`.

Note:

1. Always initialize your local variables.
2. Check the return value of `scanf()` for successful input.
3. [A request] `C` ignores white-spaces [mostly]. Use them to make your code more *human-readable*.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is this:
`int a[m]`

What you expect to be value of `m`? Change to `a[256]`. Or define `int *a` then after scanning `m`: `a = malloc( m * sizeof (int) )`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want

```
a[m];
```

From C99 you have VLA

```
int m;
scanf("%d",&m);
int a[m];
```

Because I see in your code you are trying to scan the size of the array.

Alternatively you can have a dynamic array

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * m);
```

**@Sourav** has already mentioned the reason for crash.

The value of `m` is undeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

declaration of array caused the runtime error please refer to this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm